# Gradle JAVA_HOME anomaly

Tags: java, windows, gradle, cmd, path

I am having a very weird problem with gradle and im not sure what is wrong.
Java 17 is not installed or anywhere in my path. JAVA_HOME and the java bin are correct in my path. I cant even find the "I cannot find the java executable" string in the gradle.bat or gradle files. Thank you.

[CMD with where gradle and gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTcv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue with Gradle: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18092

Comment: Thank you. Ill follow the issue.